# Angular HTML 5 Input display nothing when decimal is null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Here is my input which right now displays NaN if vehicle.total is null.

```
<input id="total" class="form-control" placeholder="Job Amount" 
 data-ng-model="vehicle.total" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" 
 value="vehicle.total" name="total"/>
```

How can I get the input to not display NaN and be empty instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null is Not a Number (NaN) so as long as that is null that is what will be displayed without providing some logic to capture the null value and display zero.

An easier and simpler method would be to manually instantiate vehicle.total to 0 in the controller.

You could also use ngInit but it is not recommended. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: I understand that but was hoping the user wouldn't have to see that or zero unless they explicitly typed a zero. If total was null i was hoping to keep it that way or have it be undefined

Comment: The 0 and null would both evaluate the same, I'm not sure of your limitations but its not uncommon to declare initial states in the controller.

Comment: In my api the total is nullable due to this record coming from other sources through integrations where it doesnt make sense to have total. So if one of these records come through to my screen I dont want to put a zero on a field that never had anything to begin with.

Comment: You could use ngKeyUp to handle the input change and do all of the data binding in the controller, that way you can display an initial value of 0 without changing the null value

Comment: I cant have the user see the zero as well since that would be confusing for them. If there is a 0 than it should create a record with zero. Thanks though

Comment: You could have the input be empty, providing a 0 as the initial value is just an example.